# JQuery.js tag placement best practice MVC .net

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Where should I put my `<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` in `_Layout.cshtml` page? at the bottom or top section? now I have done my search, placing jquery.js at the bottom of the layout page will give page load performance. however, I come across a problem/error when `@RenderBody()`, the body requires to use jQuery before the script is been load and this caused `$` not defined.

[link - Layout in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

My page looks exactly like the above link.
any tips and tricks for work around the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by having a section for page scripts behind the one where jQuery is added, at the end of the page.

So create a new section (say MyScripts) below all other library scripts in `Layout`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

And in view:

```
@section MyScripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        write your jquery script...
    </script>
}
```

I highly recommended reading this article about sections in Razor: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor